# Weil divisor arising from invertible sheaf and rational section?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

I know there have been questions about this but I'm afraid I am still not really getting it. It's kind of embarrassing that something is not clicking at this point because I have asked some related questions before. I want to understand exactly what the process is for defining a Weil divisor from an invertible sheaf along with a choice of "rational section".

Throughout, let $X$ be a noetherian, integral, normal scheme.

My first confusion is precisely what is meant by rational section. Most sources just define it as "a section of $\mathcal{L}$ defined over a dense open subset". This seems to just be the definition of an element of the stalk of $\mathcal{L}$ at the generic point. Is there a reason they don't just define it this way, or is it somehow different?

In the case that $\mathcal{L}$ is just the structure sheaf, then a rational section is just a non-zero element of the quotient field of any affine open subset, call it $f \in K^{*}(X)$. Then if $Y$ is a prime Weil divisor with generic point $\eta$, then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\eta} \subseteq K^{*}(X)$ is a DVR and we obtain a valuation corresponding to it. I am having trouble reducing the invertible sheaf case to this.

Let $(\mathcal{L}, s)$ be an invertible sheaf and rational section (which I am assuming is just an element of the stalk of $\mathcal{L}$ at the generic point of $X$). Now if $Y$ is again a prime Weil divisor with generic point $\eta$, we can choose a trivialising open neighbourhood $U \ni \eta$ with trivialisation
$$
\psi: \mathcal{L}|_{U} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{U}.
$$
But it is not clear where to go from here. I want to somehow transport the element of the stalk of $\mathcal{L}$ to an element of the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_{U}$. So do I just take the colimit of this trivliaisation over open subsets inside $U$? Can someone walk me through this process in detail, because I find a lot of resources just seem to handwave and say something like "just transport the rational section" and it isn't clear to me what that means in rigorous terms.

Comment: The generic point of $X$ belongs to $U$.

Comment: So you take the colimit of open subsets of U to obtain an isomorphism of the stalk of the line bundle at the generic point of X and the stalk of the structure sheaf at the generic point of X?

Comment: If you have a morphism of sheaves $\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal G$ over any topological space $X$, this always induces a morphism at the level of stalks by taking colimits over open sets. So yes, you are correct.

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician Thank you, this is very helpful. So the only other thing I am confused about then is why it matters that we take an open subset of the generic point of the prime divisor? Why not just ANY open subset of $X$ on which the invertible sheaf trivialises? It seems like we only care about obtaining an isomorphism between the stalk of the invertible sheaf and the stalk of the structure sheaf.

Comment: You can take any trivializing open set as long as it intersects the Weil Prime divisor. That's a reasonable thing to consider since you are after all interested in that divisor. Now if you take any open set intersecting the Weil Divisor, that open set will contain the generic point of the divisor. So either way you are doing the same thing.

Comment: I realise it is the same as my queston, but my issue is that just about every resource or textbook insists on taking an open neighbourhood of the generic point of the divisor in question. That's why I was sure I was missing something. Take for example page 400 of Ravi Vakil's notes where he says "take any open set $U$ containing the
generic point of $Y$ where $\mathscr{L}$ is trivializable". The same is claimed in the stacks project for example.

Comment: But why does it even need to intersect the Weil divisor is my question?

Comment: As @KReiser points out, this is independent whether your rational section is actually defined at the generic point of $Y$.

Comment: All we need is an isomorphism from the stalk of $\mathcal{L}$ at the generic point of $X$ to the stalk of $\mathcal{O}$ at the generic point of $X$. This can be obtained via any trivalising open subset. Why does that open subset need to intersect the prime Weil divisor? I understand that it may not, but every single textbook seems to do it that way, so I thought there must be some reason it is necessary.

Comment: Does it provide some benefit in any way? Forgive my stupid question here but it just makes me uncomfortable that every single textbook specifies an open subset intersecting the divisor. It gave me the impression it was at least useful, even if not necessary.

Comment: I don't see why it matters (though perhaps I'm missing something - it is a little late where I am). The only thing I can think of is that if you're working on a non-integral scheme and trying to deal with things in different components, but you're assuming integral. (For posterity, the example was $X=\Bbb A^1_k$, $Y=(x)$, $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}$, $s=1/x$ defined on $X\setminus Y$, I accidentally deleted it.)